# Access row data in DoubleCLickListener of TableViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tableview, actionlistener, double-click

I need to show some information related to the row or cell being clicked in table of TableViewer.

As far as I understand I can use **(TableViewer) event.getViewer()** in **viewer.addDoubleClickListener()** to retrieve data of current row or cell being clicked. Correct me if I am wrong.

But my **run()** function is in **private void makeActions()** where I can't access event. How can I overcome this problem?

```java
private void hookDoubleClickAction()
{
    viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener()
    {
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event)
        {
            //TableViewer chek = (TableViewer) event.getViewer();

            doubleClickAction.run();
        }
    });
}

private void makeActions()
{
    doubleClickAction = new Action()
    {
        public void run()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the `TableViewer` as a field in your main class (or pass it as a parameter to the action constructor). You can then get the current selection from the viewer in your action using:

```java
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();
```